# Sync Framework - Changing the Database Scope

Tags: c#, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm developing a database driven WPF application which needs to support offline use, for the most part Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1 seems perfect. Except when it comes to changes to the actual database.

There's every possibility that in a months time I may need to add a column or even a table to be used in the Application which doesn't appear to be supported by the Microsoft Sync Framework at all.

Surely there must be a safe way to handle these sorts of changes? I just can't seem to find anything at all online about it!

Answer (score 0):

modifying sync scope definition is not supported in Sync Fx, but there are workarounds. I wrote a 4 part series on it some years back (1st one [here])[1](https://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/03/21/modifying-sync-framework-scope-definition-part-1-introduction/)